# How do i loop this MarketPlace_f

Tags: actionscript-3

how to i loop this Marketplace_f, so when i loop it go to a to f?

```
this.clients.multiplayer.createJoinRoom("MarketPlace_f_v92",
    "MarketPlace_f", 
    true, 
    {lobbyv:"MarketPlace_"+this.mpv},
    {namehash:"3c0073212ba7bbf142cd3c5a01f518ac",
        name:"Manuel Otto",
        name:"Manuel Otto"},
    this.handleJoin,
    null);
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question?  I have no idea what you're trying to do or how that code is related -- there's no loop in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I will take a wild guess that you want to generate strings from "MarketPlace_a" to "MarketPlace_f" :)

```
var startCode:int = 97; // ascii code for "a"
var endCode:int = 102; // ascii code for "f"

for (var i:int = startCode; i < endCode + 1; i++)
{
    // if you use AS2: var letter:String = chr(i);
    var letter:String = String.fromCharCode(i);

    var myString:String = "MarketPlace_" + letter;

    trace(myString);
}
```